# Getting empty object from async mongo.save()

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express

I have seperated my code into a controler and a database service and added in async/await to make sure I return the json response from mongo.db. Unfortunatley it keeps sending an empty object {}. Why is my await not doing anything, its just sending back an empty object. The same code applied to a simple find on an array of data returns the full mock object.

Controller

```
const postVacation = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
  const vacation: IVacation = {
    id: undefined,
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
  };
  try {
    const newVacation = await vacationData.addVacation(vacation);
    res.status(201).json(newVacation);
  } catch (error) {
    next(new HttpException(500, error.toString()));
  }
};
```

Service

```
const addVacation = async (vacation: IVacation): Promise<IVacationMongo> => {
  const createdVacation = new Vacation({
    name: vacation.name,
    description: vacation.description,
  });
  return createdVacation.save();
};
```

Models

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export interface IVacation {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

export interface IVacationMongo extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

const vacationSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Vacation = mongoose.model<IVacationMongo>("Vacation", vacationSchema);
export default Vacation;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing an await in the service

```
return await createdVacation.save();
```